# Pygame, changing screen and passing back

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a little game, but ask you could guess, i have a problem :p

My first class (it gets originalscreen from the first part of the game)

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    import pygbutton

class part():
 def __init__(self,originalscreen):

    self.screen = originalscreen
    self.part()

 def part(self):

    """ Finally: the game!"""
    # But first, some variables and imports
    parton = True
    import makemap

    # Looping
    while parton:
        # The screen
        self.screen.fill(0)
        makemap.mapmaker(self.screen)

        # Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                exit()

        # Updating the screen
        pygame.display.flip()
```

As you can read, I import makemap and pass the screen to it

```
   import pygame
   from pygame.locals import *

   """ Add tiles here"""
   grass = pygame.image.load("tiles/grass.png")

   def mapmaker(screen):
     height = screen.get_height()
     width = screen.get_width()

     # Set the size of each tile (25 pixels)
     xscale = width / 40
     yscale = height / 24

     # Loading file
     mapfile = open("part1map.txt", "r")

     # Making the map
     xco = 0
     yco = 0

     lines = mapfile.readlines()
     for line in lines:
        for typeoftile in range(0, len(line)):
            if str(typeoftile) == "g":
                screen.blit(grass, (xco*xscale, yco*yscale))
                xco = xco + 1
        yco = yco + 1
```

But then my problem occurs: my background stays black (0), so the mapmaker-function doesn't pass the screen back to my first file of code.

How can i edit the screen (like i do in mapmaker) and then display it?

I hope someone can help me
Lukas

ps: if you have any questions, please ask. And sorry for my English, I'm dutch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite fully specified -- we don't know what the map file looks like, for instance. But this part definitely looks wrong:

```
for line in lines:
    for typeoftile in range(0, len(line)):
        if str(typeoftile) == "g":
            screen.blit(grass, (xco*xscale, yco*yscale))
            xco = xco + 1
```

"typeoftile" will here be bound to a *number* between 0 and len(line) - 1. This will clearly never be the characer "g", and so the conditional will never trigger.

It seems like what you want is the corresponding *character*, not the index. The simplest fix is to insert the indexing operator like this:

```
for line in lines:
    for index in range(0, len(line)):
        typeoftile = line[index]
        if str(typeoftile) == "g":
            screen.blit(grass, (xco*xscale, yco*yscale))
            xco = xco + 1
```

However, it's a bit more elegant and "Pythonic" to iterate over the characters in a string like this:

```
for line in lines:
    for typeoftile in line:
        if str(typeoftile) == "g":
            screen.blit(grass, (xco*xscale, yco*yscale))
            xco = xco + 1
```

Assuming "line" is a string, "typeoftile" will then be bound to each of the characters in the string in sequence. ("abc" works just the same as ["a","b","c"] when it comes to iterating over the characters like this.)